# android google maps api v2 custom markers onMarkerClick does not work

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

when creating a custom marker with a custom icon when you clicked on the marker after 2-3 times than the map does not fire the onMarkerClick event or any other event like onMapClick etc.. is that a bug or there is any kind of a solution for that ?

just to be clear the scenario is as follow :
1)you are in a certain zoom level
2)you press the marker you zoom in to X zoom level the info window is shown
3)at the last zoom level the you were(without moving on the map) you just press again on the same marker and everything is workin as its should
4)you press it again and nothing happen the info window is gone and till you will not move on the map you can not interact with the marker

Comment: Did you remember to set the listeners?

Comment: In the 'onMarkerClick' method, set return value to 'true'.